# React-Router v4: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Tags: react-router

I want to redirect when I hit a button, so I used the `withRouter` to get the access to the history props.

But I get the error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
  at Route.computeMatch (react-router.js:1160)
```

error when I wrap my component with the `withRouter` HOC.
If I remove `withRouter` function, it just works.

My code looks like the following:

```
class App extends Component {

// ...some unrelated functions

handleTitleTouchTap = e => {
    e.preventDefault()
    const { history } = this.props
    history.push('/')
}

render() {
                //...other components
        <Router>
            <div>      
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact={true} path="/" component={Home} />
                    <Route path="/search" component={Search}/>
                    <Route path="/gamelist/:listId" component={GameListDetail}/>
                    <Route path="/game/:gameId" component={GameDetail}/>
                    <Route path="/manageuser" component={ManageUser} />
                    <Route path="/addgamelist" component={AddGameList} />
                    <Route path="/addgame" component={AddGame} />
                    <Route path="/test" component={Test} />
                    <Route component={NoMatch} />
                </Switch>
                <LoginForm isLoginFormOpen={isLoginFormOpen} closeLoginForm={closeLoginForm} handleLogin={handleLogin}/>
                <RegisterForm isRegisterFormOpen={isRegisterFormOpen} closeRegisterForm={closeRegisterForm} register={register}/>
            </div>
        </Router>
    )
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    //some props
})
const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => ({
    //some functions
})
const Container = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)

export default withRouter(Container)
```

Comment: exactly the same problem here

Comment: Where are you using `<Container>`?

Comment: Hi @leuction, any chances that my answer helped you?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've got the same issue and I solved it enclosing the wrapped component in a `Router` component (namely `BrowserRouter`).

In your example, it would become:

```
// assuming this file is Container.js
export default withRouter(Container)


// index.js
import Container from './Container'

render(
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Container/>
    </BrowserRouter>,
    document.getElementById('root')
 )
```

Working example from the docs here: https://codepen.io/pietro909/pen/RVWmwZ

I also opened an issue on the repo because the example from the docs is not clear enough in my opinion https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4994.

Comment: I use the react-router-redux solving this problem either. This is a quite strange bug.