# React-Router - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-v4

Trying to use react router v4 with redux and running into this error, seem to be following the docs, couldn't find any information anywhere on it so I'm at a loss:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined

Here's my code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Link,
  withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Menu from './Menu';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Play from './Play';
class Manager extends Component {
    render() {
        return(
             <Router>
                <div>
                  <Route exact path="/" component={Menu}/>
                  <Route path="/menu" component={Menu}/>
                  <Route path="/play" component={Play}/>
                </div>
              </Router>
        )
    }
}
export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Manager));
```

and here's the full error:

```
game.js:26838 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined
    at Route.computeMatch (game.js:26838)
    at new Route (game.js:26815)
    at game.js:15322
    at measureLifeCyclePerf (game.js:15102)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponentWithoutOwner (game.js:15321)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper._constructComponent (game.js:15307)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (game.js:15215)
    at Object.mountComponent (game.js:7823)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.performInitialMount (game.js:15398)
    at ReactCompositeComponentWrapper.mountComponent (game.js:15285)
```

Comment: Did you try to change `from 'react-router-dom'` to `from 'react-router'`?

Comment: Try importing withRouter from 'react-router' like `import {withRouter} from 'react-router'`

Comment: Neither of those approaches work either unfortunately.

Comment: no solutions yet? this problem is utterly annoying

Comment: I've answered the same question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175941/react-router-v4-cannot-read-property-route-of-undefined/43483274#43483274 please check it out and see if it solves your problem, too.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [React-Router v4: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175941/react-router-v4-cannot-read-property-route-of-undefined)

Comment: Like Антон Досов writes below, you are using withRouter higher than your <Router /> component. You only need withRouter for connected children of the above component.

Answer (score 4):

Here,you are using react-router-dom latest version above 4.0.0.

So,there is no Router available. You need to use BrowserRouter in this version.

your code will be

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {
  Switch,
 Route,
 Link,
 withRouter
} from 'react-router-dom'
import Menu from './Menu';
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import Play from './Play';
class Manager extends Component {
   render() {
    return(<div>
         <Switch>

              <Route exact path="/" component={Menu}/>
              <Route path="/menu" component={Menu}/>
              <Route path="/play" component={Play}/>

          </Switch></div>
    )
}
}
 export default withRouter(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Manager));
```

and use BrowserRouter in your index.js file to render this Component

```
import { BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
ReactDOM.render((<BrowserRouter><Manager/></BrowserRouter>), document.getElementById('root'));
```

Answer (score 2):

change your router to a new react router 4.0 called "react-router-dom"

using npm/yarn install the module "react-router-dom", define your router like so..

don't forget imports.
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

```
         <BrowserRouter>
              <div>
              <Route exact path="/" component={Menu}/>
              <Route path="/menu" component={Menu}/>
              <Route path="/play" component={Play}/>
              </div>
          </BrowserRouter>
```

Comment: if you still have problems feel free to message me :)

Comment: Hi i am getting same error  "TypeError: Cannot read property 'router' of undefined" I have installed react-router-dom module by doing npm install react-router-dom and also import module and tried to redirect via "this.props.router.push('/#/dashboard')"

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use withRouter higher than your actual Router is :)
Just remove it:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(Manager);
```

You will need to use withRouter HOC, if you want to access history information inside the component nested in Route. You can find details here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/withRouter

Answer (score 0):

So I was running this off my local server, when I ran it off a webpack server it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this by moving my `<Navigation />` inside my `<Router></Router>`