# React(v4) - exporting component with withRouter returns error

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

This problem might be a bug according to another post here [React-Router v4: Cannot read property 'route' of undefined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175941/react-router-v4-cannot-read-property-route-of-undefined) and apparently the person solved their problem by wrapping their routers in a browserRouter.  However, I have done that already and still seem to be getting the error.  Just like the other post, when I export my component with withRouter, it returns an error, however when I export it without it, it works fine.  What I am trying to do is, find the pathname when a person loads a Route, check to see if they are authenitcated, if not, redirect to login, if they are, redirect to home.   I've had this problem for a while now, if you know a solution please help me.

**Routes.js**

```
import { Meteor } from "meteor/meteor"
import React from "react";
import { withRouter, Switch, BrowserRouter, Route, Redirect, Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Tracker } from "meteor/tracker";

import Login from "../ui/authentication/Login";
import Signup from "../ui/authentication/Signup";
import Home from "../ui/Home";
import searchNotes from "../ui/searchNotes"
import Note from "../ui/Note";
import fullSize from "../ui/fullSize"
import userProfile from "../ui/userProfile";
import AddNote from "../ui/AddNote";
import questions from "../ui/questions"
import NotFound from "../ui/NotFound";

  export default class Routes extends React.Component{
  render(){
    const signedIn = Meteor.userId();
    const UnauthPage = ["/login", "/signup"];
    console.log(this.props)
    // if(signedIn && ){
    //   console.log("Signed in")
    // }
    return (
        <BrowserRouter>
          <Switch>
            <Login path="/login" />
            <Signup path="/signup" />
            <Route path="/" component={Home} exact/>
            <Route path={`/searchNotes/:subject`} component={Note} />
            <Route path={`/searchNotes`} component={searchNotes} />
            <Route path={`/fullSize/:noteId`} component={fullSize}/>
            <AddNote path="/addNote"/>
            <Route path="/questions" component={questions} />
            <Route component={userProfile} path={`/users/:userId`} />
            <NotFound />
          </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: `Login`, `Signup`, `AddNote` and `Not found` are regular components?

Comment: yes, they are all also exported with withRouter

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you still have to create a Route for them. `<Route path="/login component={Login} />` same goes for the others.

Comment: Is that not what I did when I did <Login path="/login" />?

Comment: I've never seen that syntax for a Route. Just use it like the others `<Route path="/login component={Login} />`

Comment: Someone in a another post told me either one works, they're the same thing, Ill try switching them and see if it works.........it does not, still the same error

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/153305/discussion-between-stuart-fong-and-edgar-henriquez).

Comment: Which one of those components using `withRouter`? Please share the codes.